# Is there any method of making local 'defonce'? (Clojure)

Tags: clojure, counter, local, private, encapsulation

Let's say I need to make a simple counter and I want counter to be incremented each time I call this function, but here is one unpleasant thing: defined 'counter' is not local and I can easily change its value from another space, that breaks encapsulation.

```
(defn next []
  (defonce counter (atom 0))
  (println @counter)
  (reset! counter (inc @counter)))
```

Many say, it will be correct if I place 'private' meta tag. So function will look like this:

```
(defn next []
  (defonce ^:private counter (atom 0))
  (println @counter)
  (reset! counter (inc @counter)))
```

But I still have access to 'counter' from another space.
Is there any way to implement this encapsulation or it's only at the agreement level?

Comment: Are you sure you have access to private atom from another ns?

Comment: @mishadoff [Yes.](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide/blob/cb0be3a21c234fbb5bd152e3d67ffbf104140077/README.md#access-private-var)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you should write your `next` function:

```
(def ^{:arglists '([])} next
  (let [counter (atom 0)]
    #(let [after (swap! counter inc)
           before (dec after)]
       (println before)
       after)))
```

This is the same as the one in your question, except that it is thread-safe and completely encapsulates the `counter` atom.

Comment: Perfectly! But... `^{:arglists '([])}` - what is this for?

Comment: @errfrom It's not really necessary; try `(clojure.repl/doc next)` with and without it and you can decide whether you want to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Private works well, you shouldn't have access from other namespace

```
user> (ns a)
nil
a> (defonce ^:private counter (atom 0))
#'a/counter
a> (defn next [] 
     (println @counter)
     (swap! counter inc))
#'a/next
a> (next)
0
1
a> (next)
1
2
a> (next)
2
3
a> (next)
3
4
a> (ns b)
nil
b> (require 'a)
nil
b> (a/next)
4
5
b> (a/next)
5
6
b> a/counter
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalStateException: var: a/counter is not public
b> (ns a)
nil
a> a/counter
#object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x1ec64eb6 {:status :ready, :val 6}]
```

Also some minor issues:

1. define `counter` at the top level of ns, not inside the function, both have the same effect, but top level is clearer
2. change `reset!` to `(swap! counter inc)`, it will be thread safe

Comment: There was a small misunderstanding: I want counter to be only in this function with no access from the top level as a local binding 'let' do. Is it possible?

Comment: @errfrom well, I don't think you can hide local mutable inside a function with no access from outside. Use defrecord or deftype instead (similar to creating a Counter object in java)

Comment: I revised my code and decided I should put the part of it in a separate module, where defining at the top level wouldn't create any problems, so basically the problem is solved. Thank you =)